# Not sure where to use asyncTask in fragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment, android-adapter

Hello guys im working on project that should use themoviedb.org api to get data about movies. I have fragment that attached to my main activity and i built an adapter. My problem is that i want to use picasso to load movie posters from themoviedb.org and to do that i need to read "poster_path" from json data. I made async task that take all the "poster_path" from json data and saved that strings in string array that i declared in asynctask class. Now i dont sure where should i execute the asynctask in the fragment and how to pass that array to my adapter so it can use it

Comment: Fire the `AsyncTask` off in `onCreate()` and use it on `onPostExecute()` of your `AsyncTask` definition.

Comment: Please show your code as a [mcve].

Comment: Have you considered using other, easier networking libraries like Retrofit, OkHttp, or Volley?

Comment: Posibble dublicate? 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080197/loading-image-using-picasso-inside-asynctask

Comment: @Knossos what you mean by "use it on postExecute" do you mean to make listview in the fragment and use it in postExecute() like arraylist.add? And if you mean so does it thread safe?

Comment: One of the key methods of `AsyncTask` is `onPostExecute()`. You need to override that. It runs on the UI Thread, so it is the best place to update your Adapter from.

Comment: Should i write in my adapter class public arraylist array= new arraylist() and then thru the onpostexecute() use it? @Knossos

Comment: You would be best served [reading the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) about this, and looking at [some examples](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#example-asynctask).

Comment: @Knossos i got it if thats subclass of my fragment that i can use the arraylist and use it. But if i want to make it in separate class i have to make the arraylist public static and i wonder if thats right way of coding

Answer (score 0):

- Create a `Bean` or `Pojo` class
- Create **setters** and **getters**
- Create `AsyncTask` in `onCreate()`
- Fetch data from **API**, and make a **ArrayList** of your contents
- Pass **ArrayList** to **Adapter**
- And set content to views in **Adapter Class**

To easily achieve your requirements.

For example-

Your Pojo class should be like as-

```
public class Contact {

public int id;
public String contacName;
public String contactEmail;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getContacName() {
    return contacName;
}

public void setContacName(String contacName) {
    this.contacName = contacName;
}

public String getContactEmail() {
    return contactEmail;
}

public void setContactEmail(String contactEmail) {
    this.contactEmail = contactEmail;
}
```

}

Your adapter class should be like as -

```
    public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.mViewHolder>  {

    // list of Contact type items
    private List<Contact> contactList;


    public ContactAdapter(List<Contact> contactList){
        this.contactList = contactList;
    }
    @Override
    public mViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    //inflaing item layout and return to holder
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_contact,
                parent,false);
        return new mViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(mViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //Binding data with views
        Contact mContect = contactList.get(position);
        holder.txtName.setText(mContect.getContacName());
        holder.txtEmail.setText(mContect.getContactEmail());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contactList.size();
    }

    public static class mViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtEmail;

        public mViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
            txtEmail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contactEmail);

        }
    }
}
```

Now create a list of Pojo class like `List<Contact> contactsList = new ArrayList<>;`. Now parse your Json data accrodingly, like set Contact name as

```
Contact contact = new Contact(); 
contact.setName("your String fetched from Json");
contact.setEmail("your String fetched from Json");
contactList.add(contact);
```

You can pass your data to adapter as we created a constructor in Adapter class.
like: `ContactAdapter adapter = new ContactAdapter(contactList);`

Take it an example and try to implement yourself.

Comment: thank you i have another question is where should i declare the arraylist if in the asynctask class so how to pass to adapter and if in the bean or fragment how to add data from that the asynctask to that

Comment: forgot to tag you before

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ take it an example for better understanding, how to parse Json data and bind data with adapter.

Comment: Saw the exaple but if i want my asyncTask in different class i have to make the arraylist public static is it right way to do that?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve this, create a public class and method and get data from it. Create a constructor, and then you can call that method in any class you want.